# How to implement recursive function in While loop Module, calling on other functions

Tags: scoping, iterators

I am trying to implement a module such that it " takes a distance matrix, Q, and iterates
the corresponding “Bellman operator” module written above until a final cost-to-go
function (i.e. J) is found." [i.e. relaxing edges in shortest path problem with J converging from 0 to a final cost-to-go]. However, I cannot seem to get it to work, having tried a variety of methods (While, NestWhile, MapThread). Below is my best attempt

```
findCostToGo2[Q_, bellmanOperator_] := Module[{J, i},
  J[1] = bellmanOperator;
  J[2] = bellmanIteration[Q, bellmanOperator];
  J[i_] := J[i] = bellmanIteration[Q, J[i - 1]]; 
  While[{J[i - 1] != J[i - 2]}, J[i]]]
```

where Q is a 100x100 array with various edge-weights as entries [EDIT: bellmanOperator in the above code is actually the list output by running bellmanIteration[Q,(*list of 100 zeroes*)]]. When I run this Module, however, this is the output

```
findCostToGo2[Q, startingpoint]

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of -1019+i$49205.

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of -1019+i$18840.

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of -1019+i$18840.

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of bellmanIteration[{{\[Infinity],0.04,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],11.11,\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],20.59,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],2.06,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],0.73,\[Infinity],1.02,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],3.33,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],0.72,<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],3.15,<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},<<90>>},J$18166[i$18166]].

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of bellmanIteration[{{\[Infinity],0.04,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],11.11,\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],20.59,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],2.06,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],0.73,\[Infinity],1.02,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],3.33,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],0.72,<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],3.15,<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},<<90>>},J$18150[i$18150]].

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of bellmanIteration[{{\[Infinity],0.04,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],11.11,\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],20.59,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],2.06,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],0.73,\[Infinity],1.02,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],3.33,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],0.72,<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],3.15,<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},<<90>>},J$18137[i$18137]].

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of bellmanIteration[{{\[Infinity],0.04,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],11.11,\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],20.59,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],2.06,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],0.73,\[Infinity],1.02,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],3.33,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],0.72,<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],3.15,<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},<<90>>},J$18121[i$18121]].

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of bellmanIteration[{{\[Infinity],0.04,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],11.11,\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],20.59,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],2.06,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],0.73,\[Infinity],1.02,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],3.33,\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],0.72,<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],3.15,<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},{\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],\[Infinity],<<90>>},<<90>>},J$18107[i$18107]].
```

Anyone able to write a module that gets this to run? Below is my bellmanIteration module, which, when I edit it to output `J[n+98]`, gives the output I want from my above module. However this is a somewhat arbitrary number of iterations and I'd rather use a While loop condition.

```
bellmanIteration[Q_, Jguess_] := Module[
  {J, n, v, w},
  J[n] = Jguess;
  J[i_] := 
   J[i] = Table[
     Min[Table[Q[[v, w]] + J[i - 1][[w]], {w, Length[Q]}]], {v, 
      Length[Q]}];
  J[n + 1]]
```

Comment: Try `i = 2;
While[J[i] != J[i - 1],
  ++i;
  J[i];
  ];`.

Comment: Alternatively, `FixedPointList[bellmanIteration[Q, #] &, bellmanOperator]` should also do the trick.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher both ways seem to work, thanks. As neither seems quicker than the other for my purposes, I'll opt for the FixedPointList which is more streamlined.